# Zero Crossing Optoisolator in Multisim

Tags: simulation, zero-crossing, multisim

I'm an electronics hobbist with relatively little experience and I'm playing around with Multisim to try to understand how to manipulate AC waveforms.  Specifically, I would like to control the wave form with a function generator, optoisolator, and a triac.  I'm unable to find an optoisolator in Multisim that has zero crossing, which as I understand it is somewhat important when trying to manipulate the waveform.  Something like the [MOC3041](http://search.digikey.com/us/en/products/MOC3041M/MOC3041M-ND/281230) (Output Type - AC, Triac, Zero Cross) is what I've been reading is a fairly standard component used to do this, but it's not listed in Multisim.  Where should I look to find something that will work?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't know anything about mulitim, but can't you make your own components as needed?  Also, the parameter "zero crossing detection" makes no sense for a optoisolator.  Perhaps you are thinking about solid state relays?

Comment: @Olin Lathrop You'll have to bear with me.  I'm fairly new to this.  When I say optoisolator with zero crossing detection I mean one that will not switch on until the wave form is at zero.  I could probably make my own, but since these are sold through electronics vendors, I would like to make something as close to reality as possible.  I can't be sure that anything I created would be "real".  Anyway, thanks for your comments.  Maybe what I want to do isn't possible.  That's an acceptable answer too.

Comment: here is some help
http://www.cel.com/pdf/appnotes/an3005.pdf http://www.picaxeforum.co.uk/showthread.php?12630-Custom-sub-circuit-model-VTL5C6-analog-opto-isolator

Comment: @George Yes, that is helpful!  I didn't consider the fact that PSPICE doesn't have the ability to do analysis of optics, which is probably by it doesn't include an optocoupler by default.  Thank you!

Comment: Sorry I can't help with simulating that particular chip in Multisim. You might also want to experiment with non-zero-cross AC waveform manipulation -- [light dimmer simulation](http://myweb.msoe.edu/~jevtic/EE444_F08/wp-content/myData/Simulations/Sim2.pdf) and [triac simulation](http://forums.ni.com/t5/Circuit-Design-Suite-Multisim/Triac-Problems/td-p/577013).

Comment: @Matt Ruwe - Optoisolators don't have zero-crossing detection, or anything else like that at all. They're just a photodiode/transistor and a LED in a box. What you are referring to is an aspect of *one specific type* of **solid-state relay**, which is basically an opto-isolator **with a bunch of additional components** on the pohtotransistor/diode side of the opto.

Comment: @ConnorWolf There are indeed opto-isolator ICs with built-in zero crossing detectors. Just Google **opto-isolator with a zero crossing detector**.

Answer (score -1):

Multisim is based on SPICE which is unable to simulate optical components like the MOC3041 that I used.  Given this, the answer to the question is Multisim is unable to simulate a MOC3041.

Comment: I don't see any reason spice couldn't simulate the transfer function of an opto. Also, the MOC3041 isn't just an opto. It's an opto with a bunch of additional components on the output. For all intents and purposes, it's basically (most of) a solid-state relay (and the manufacturer calling it just an "Optoisolator" is really rather misleading).

Comment: Avago has a page of SPICE models for their opto-isolators [here](http://www.avagotech.com/pages/optocouplers_plastic/spicemodels/). You will have to add the zero-crossing detector and the TRIAC output stage yourself.

Comment: @Fake Name Great info, I was mostly posting this answer to my question because I didn't want to leave it open.  If you would like to post you comment as an answer, I'll accept it.